# Adding in jQuery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

I was watching a video tutorial on adding jQuery validation to contact forms, but none of it is working. They never really discussed how to add the validate plugin to the page, so I am thinking that may be where I am going wrong.

The jQuery call out he had at the top of his page was this:

`<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

Again, he didn't go into it more than to google jQuery validate and that it would show up, so I assumed that it was this:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Does anyone see anything wrong with what I did for it to not work? I got the actual form to work, just not the jQuery validate.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#contactform").validate({
   rules: {
    name: {
     required: true;
     minlength: 2
    },
    email: {
     required: true;
     email: true;
    },
    message: {
     required: true;
     minlength: 5
    }
   },
   messages: {
    name: {
     required: "Please enter your name",
     minlength: "Your name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
    },
    email: {
     required: "Please enter your email address",
     email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    message: {
     required: "Please enter your message",
     minlength: "Your message seems a bit short. Please enter at least 5 characters"
    }
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="" novalidate>

   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
   <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Send">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set values for object properties you should place `,` after values instead of `;`. So change `required: true;` (three places), `email: true;` to `required: true,` and `email: true,`

Then your code will work, like here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/wgtLnxfw/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Is there anyway that I can add style to the JS errors that come up when something was inputted wrong?

Comment: Sure. Add css to class `.error`. I updated fiddle in my answer.

Comment: How did you know to do that, though? There isn't an error class even mentioned?

Comment: If you use Chrome as a browser, right-click any element on page and in the context menu click the bottom item 'Inspect'. It will take you to the element markup. It was there that I saw error messages had `error` class.

Comment: Gotcha!!!! Makes sense. One more question if you don't mind. If I wanted this form to hide after I submitted it and then bring up a success form, can I add `success: function (data) {` to the end of my current javascript and do a show/hide function?

Comment: Or would I have to create an AJAX script for this and send it to a new php file?

Comment: I think you would rather use `submitHandler: function(){ ... }`, which will be called on submit button click if form is valid, to start ajax request and then show success form in `success` callback of ajax when you get a positive confirmation from server.

Comment: So you are saying to use Ajax too? I'm confused?

Comment: What is supposed to happen after you submit the form: 1) will it reload page or go to some other url, or 2) would you like to keep current page and only refresh some part of it? If (1) than no ajax is required. Then you just submit the form as usual and show success or errors on a new page that will come as a response to your php request you specify in form's `action` attribute. If (2) you need to send form with ajax instead; you will need to remove `action` attribute to avoid autosubmitting and create an ajax request; it is easy - [jQuery ajax post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Comment: I just want to be able to hide the form after a successful submit and then show a new container afterwords with something like "Thanks for contacting us!"

Comment: You can add `submitHandler: function(){ ... }` to your validate config and place inside such functionality. But I'm not sure the user will have time to read it because your form will be submitting the same moment and page may have been refreshed by the time you would show success form.

Comment: Ok. Can't I just add an event.prevent function?

Comment: You mean to delay submitting form to show messages to user? If think yes, you can do this with `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed responses!

Comment: I tried to do this. Getting stuck on it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972869/form-not-submitting-when-trying-to-use-jquerys-submithandler