# Form not submitting when trying to use jQuery's submitHandler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am converting a contact form to AJAX, so that I can do the success function. Right now the code is stopping at the submitHandler section saying that it is undefined. How is my submitHandler not defined?

`submitHandler(function(form) {`

Am I doing this in the correct way, though? I want to use my current php because I built it to be back-end validation on-top of the jQuery validation.

Does anyone see what is wrong with the submitHandler and anything that may be preventing this from sending?

HTML

```
<div class="contact-container">
    <form id="contactform" method="post" action="" novalidate>
        <?php 
            if($sent === true) {
                echo "<h2 class='success'>Thanks, your message has been sent successfully</h2>";
            } elseif($hasError === true) {
                echo '<ul class="errorlist">';
                foreach($errorArray as $key => $val) {
                    echo "<li>" . ucfirst($key) . " field error - $val</li>";
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        ?>
        <div>
        <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo (isset($name) ? $name : ""); ?>" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="email" class="contact_input" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo (isset($email) ? $email : ""); ?>" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div>
        <textarea name="message" class="contact_input" id="message" placeholder="Message"><?php echo (isset($message) ? $message : ""); ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_contact" class="clear" name="submitform" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="contact-email-success">
    <div class="contact-email-success-container">
        <div id="contact-email-success-title">THANK YOU FOR CONTACTING OUR AGENCY!</div>
        <div id="contact-email-success-description">Your submission has been received and one of our team members will contact you shortly.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
//Send the project email
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#submit_contact").on("click", function (event) {
        //event.preventDefault();

        $("#contactform").validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Please enter your name",
                    minlength: "Your name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email address",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                },
                message: {
                    required: "Please enter your message",
                    minlength: "Your message seems a bit short. Please enter at least 5 characters"
                }
            }
        });

        submitHandler(function(form) {

            //Variables for the form ids
            var name    = $("#name").val();
            var email   = $("#email").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();


                $.ajax({
                    url: "email-contact.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "project_name": name,
                        "title_roll":   email,
                        "project_email": message
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                        if (data == "Error!") {
                            alert("Unable to send email!");
                            alert(data);
                        } else {
                            $(".contact-container").addClass("removeClass");
                            $(".contact-email-success").show();
                            $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                            $(".announcement_success").show();
                           // $('.announcement_success').html('Email Successfully sent!');
                           //$('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                        //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                    }
                });
        }); 
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$hasError = false;
$sent = false;

$name       = $_POST['name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$message    = $_POST['message'];

if(isset($_POST['submitform'])) {
    $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES));
    $email = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
    $message = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES));

    $fieldsArray = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'message' => $message
    );

    $errorArray = array();

    foreach($fieldsArray as $key => $val) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'name':
            case 'message':
            if(empty($val)) {
                $hasError = true;
                $errorArray[$key] = ucfirst($key) . " field was left empty.";
            }
            break;
            case 'email':
                if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $hasError = true;
                    $errorArray[$key] = "Invalid Email Address entered";
                } else {
                    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    if($hasError !== true) {
        $to = "gsdfa";
        $subject = "Contact Form Submitted";
        $msgcontents = "Name: $name<br>Email: $email<br>Message: $message";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
        $headers .= "From: $name <$email> \r\n";
        $emailsent = mail($to, $subject, $msgcontents,$headers);
        if($mailsent) {
            $sent = true;
            unset($name);
            unset($email);
            unset($message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error ???? On error reporting

Comment: @devpro Yes, it is saying my `submitHandler(function(form) {` is not defined.

Comment: do you added jquery library?

Comment: Use event.preventDefault(); inside in submithandler...

Comment: Yes, I have the jQuery library. When I put the even.preventDefault() inside the submithandler it reloads the page, but before I even hit submit, it is still saying that the submithandler is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `submitHandler` inside `validate()` function call. But you are just trying to execute it outside. Make it this way -

```
$("#contactform").validate({
        rules: {...},
        messages: {...},
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            //Variables for the form ids
            var name    = $("#name").val();
            var email   = $("#email").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();


            $.ajax({
                url: "email-contact.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "project_name": name,
                    "title_roll":   email,
                    "project_email": message
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                    if (data == "Error!") {
                        alert("Unable to send email!");
                        alert(data);
                    } else {
                        $(".contact-container").addClass("removeClass");
                        $(".contact-email-success").show();
                        $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                        $(".announcement_success").show();
                       // $('.announcement_success').html('Email Successfully sent!');
                       //$('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                    //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                }
            });
        }
});
```

See the examples in [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) documentation.

Comment: So, I would all of my ajax, success and error code inside of the submitHander?

Comment: Yes, just use the same codes you have inside your submitHandler function.

Comment: It is not showing that the submithandler is an unexpected identifier

Comment: Are you saying to add this? ` $(form).ajaxSubmit();` under the submithander?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for you, as you are sending the ajax call other way. But from where the new error you are getting? JS or PHP ?

Comment: My error is JS, it is in my console. This line: `submitHandler(function(form) {` is getting : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Why are you still using that ? Didn't you made the change I suggested?

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong line. I am getting that error for the suggestion you made as well: `submitHandler: function(form) {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101503/discussion-between-tareq-mahmood-and-paul).

Answer (score 1):

use this:

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit_contact").click(function(){
         event.preventDefault();
        var name    = $("#name").val();
            var email   = $("#email").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();


                $.ajax({
                    url: "email-contact.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "project_name": name,
                        "title_roll":   email,
                        "project_email": message
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                        if (data == "Error!") {
                            alert("Unable to send email!");
                            alert(data);
                        } else {
                            $(".contact-container").addClass("removeClass");
                            $(".contact-email-success").show();
                            $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                            $(".announcement_success").show();
                           // $('.announcement_success').html('Email Successfully sent!');
                           //$('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                        //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                    }
                });
   });
});
```

And in your php file change:

```
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$message    = $_POST['message'];
```

into

```
$name       = $_POST['project_name'];
$email      = $_POST['title_roll'];
$message    = $_POST['project_email'];
```

hope its help

Comment: yea missing " ;) , tnx

Comment: I modified this and kept in my validate...which doesn't work now......but it is sending to my php file, but it is not doing anything.

Comment: please open your inspect element (f12) then go to network tab , make new request and say what is happen in your xhr request

Comment: I'm not getting a response back in my network tab from the email-contact.php either.

Comment: In the headers it is showing that this is the form data: contact_name:gfdsa
contact_email:bopb
contact_message:gfdsaga

Comment: please comment this line :if(isset($_POST['submitform'])) { and try again

Comment: I did that. Then I got an error for these lines: ` $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES));
    $email = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
    $message = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES));` so I commented them out and now I am not getting any response and no email.

Comment: How can I make this work with the validation, though? That was the main reason I was doing all of this.

Comment: first of all , your problem fix?

Comment: No. The email is not sending and the validating is not working.

Comment: put validate function before ajax call, and try again

Comment: The validate function was always before the ajax call, but I moved the submithandler inside of the validate parenthesis and now I get an error saying the submithandler is an unexpected identifier

Comment: do you have team viewer ?

Comment: Not sure what that is. I can put the code into a copy

Comment: Teamviewer is software that i can , come to your system and manage your code remotely

Comment: The validation is the main key to this though. One of the things you said to me before allowed the message to send and my success function to work, but there is an error in the php too. I need all of this to work with validation.

Comment: i know that , but for debugging , we must check which part have problem, so if your ajax call work fine , then go into your php file and echo your post variable , and see the value . if correct check your email part.if all things ok, then add validation.

Comment: I think this part in my php is wrong: `$fieldsArray = array(
  'name' => $name,
  'email' => $email,
  'message' => $message
 );
 
 $errorArray = array();
 
 foreach($fieldsArray as $key => $val) {
  switch ($key) {
   case 'name':
   case 'message':` Before I had it on the same page as my contact form, and I wasn't sending the data over, I was finding it when submitted.

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert it.

Comment: echo $hasError before your if , and tell what you see